# Inter-Rater Reliability/Agreement between "One Rater and Rest of Raters"

Tags: agreement-statistics

A snapshot of the partial rating information is given below:
[image]

- This example is based on the rating scale range [1-9].
- The blank field indicates that ith rater has never rated the jth ratee.

My first objective here is to find out the Inter-Rater Reliability between:

(i) Rater-1 vs Rest of Raters (i.e. Rater-2, Rater-3, Rater-4, Rater-5, Rater-6)

(ii) Rater-2 vs Rest of Raters (i.e. Rater-1, Rater-3, Rater-4, Rater-5, Rater-6)

(iii) Rater-3 vs Rest of Raters (i.e. Rater-1, Rater-2, Rater-4, Rater-5, Rater-6)

(iv) Rater-4 vs Rest of Raters (i.e. Rater-1, Rater-2, Rater-3, Rater-5, Rater-6)

(v) Rater-5 vs Rest of Raters (i.e. Rater-1, Rater-2, Rater-3, Rater-4, Rater-6)

(vi) Rater-6 vs Rest of Raters (i.e. Rater-1, Rater-2, Rater-3, Rater-4, Rater-5)

Is there any IRR technique to answer the above issue? I want to compute the Inter-Rater Reliability between One Rater and Rest of the Raters.

Studying the literature on IRR, I can only find these following IRR techniques:

(i) IRR between two raters. By that I can calculate IRR between Rater-1 and Rater-2, Rater-1 and Rater-3,  Rater-1 and Rater-4,  Rater-1 and Rater-5, etc.

(ii) Overall IRR between all these multiple raters.

Please correct me if I am wrong in the above two points.

But my research is more focused on finding IRR between One Rater and Rest of the Raters.

Comment: Arnab, you can compute the correlation between 1 rater's ratings, and the averages of all the rest. So, first, correlate rater 1 with the average of raters 2 through 6. Then correlate rater 2 with raters 1 and 3 through 6. And so forth.

Comment: A different question for you: I'm trying to find citations or even just a handy "name" for this procedure (I could call it one-vs-rest, but I'm trying to determine if there's a conventional name for it).